# While writing chrome extension in JavaScript is there any way to tell if chrome browser is managed by an organization

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-workspace, google-chrome-os

I am writing a chrome extension which fetches email of logged in google account on installation of extension but I want to check in my extension that if my Chromebook is managed by an organization or not.

i.e As an IT admin for a business or school, you can manage Chromebooks and other Chrome devices, from a cloud-based Admin console. Enforce policies, set up  Chrome features for users such as force install Chrome apps and extensions, and more.

Is there any way to find that if Chromebook is managed by an organization or not through js code in extension?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are interested in knowing whether or not the extension was installed by an enterprise organization? I can think of a few ways to check if it was force installed by an organization. Also, why are you fetching the emails through an extension? Would you consider fetching the emails through Workspace Marketplace : https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace